# PSD 2 HTML/CSS/JS - are "redlines"(help guides) and 2. grid lines not the same thing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, front-end-development

I have 2 PSD projects with 2 different types of blue-sky guide lines:

1. https://s15.postimg.org/s421pj5mj/PSD.jpg
2. https://s4.postimg.org/7d9ecmr8d/two.jpg

I heard that in **1.** PSD there are so called "redlines" (help guides) 
and in **2.** PSD there are so called "grid". **What is the difference between those 2 different guide line types?**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "redlines". Do you perhaps mean Smart Guides? They aren't red, they're magenta. There's a tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btPWT_nqmZU)

Comment: @BillyKerr I guess they can be any color you want them to be as you can set it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Redlining** refers to **documenting the properties of elements in a design document**, typically in red, but these are lines and specifications that you put in manually to specify dimensions, colors, fonts, etc, so that developers can implement the design. It is different from just showing the guidelines you might have used in constructing the design.

Here's an example:

[image: Redlining example]

But your document seems to be using only regular guides, not redlining.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. They are **all** guides as far as Photoshop is concerned.

Now you may place guides to indicate a grid layout, as in your second image. But they are still just guides.

(Never head of "redlines" before).